# How can we mock a response from another class using Mockito while unit testing

Tags: java, mockito

I have a method to test which is calling another class to get some information:

```
public ClassToTest {

    public void methodToTest() {
        AnotherClass ac = Factory.getInstance();
        ResponseObj response = ac.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

AnotherClass is part of another JAR and I would like to mock the response from it(to be specific mock ResponseObj response)

How can I achieve that using Mockito?

Comment: [My article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) may give you some ideas.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem That's a good article +1

Answer (score 6):

First you need is to make your class testable. It means you need to extract object creation (`AnotherClass ac = Factory.getInstance()`) from your `methodToTest` to instance field or maybe separate method (to be able to mock it), or even better - create object outside of your class and pass it via constructor. As a result, your class under test should look like:

```
public class ClassToTest {

    private AnotherClass ac;

    public ClassToTest(AnotherClass ac) {
        this.ac = ac;
    }

    public void methodToTest() {
        ResponseObj response = ac.anotherMethod();
        response.smth();
    }
}
```

Then you need to declare AnotherClass and ResponseObj as fields in test class, and initialize them as a mocks.

```
AnotherClass ac = Mockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);
ResponseObj responseMock = Mockito.mock(ResponseObj.class);
```

After that you can mock method call:

```
when(anotherClassMock.anotherMethod()).thenReturn(responseMock);
```

At the end your test class should look like:

```
public class ClassToTestTest {

    private AnotherClass anotherClassMock = mock(AnotherClass.class);
    private ResponseObj responseMock = mock(ResponseObj.class);
    private ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(anotherClassMock);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(anotherClassMock.anotherMethod()).thenReturn(responseMock);

        classToTest.methodToTest();

        verify(responseMock, only()).smth();
    }
}
```

And in case you couldn't change public API of your ClassToTest, you can use approach with Mockito spy and protected method.

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public void methodToTest() {
        AnotherClass ac = constructAnotherClassObj();
        ResponseObj response = ac.anotherMethod();
        response.smth();
    }

    protected AnotherClass constructAnotherClassObj() {
        return Factory.getInstance();
    }
}


public class ClassToTestTest {

    private AnotherClass anotherClassMock = mock(AnotherClass.class);
    private ResponseObj responseMock = mock(ResponseObj.class);
    private ClassToTest classToTest = spy(new ClassToTest());

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(anotherClassMock.anotherMethod()).thenReturn(responseMock);
        when(classToTest.constructAnotherClassObj()).thenReturn(anotherClassMock);

        classToTest.methodToTest();

        verify(responseMock, only()).smth();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution would work perfectly had been I could include the constructor. Can you suggest a solution where I can achieve the same without changing structure of ClassToBeTested? I have constraints on it.

Comment: And another 3rd option you may want to apply is PowerMock, which allows to mock static method calls, like Factory.getInstance()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried approach 2 by creating a protected method and spy. in that case responseMock always comes to be null. Is that expected ?

Comment: Shouldn't be any exceptions here, unless you don't have any exceptions inside your methods which you mock. And remember, that when you mock method calls like - when(...).thenReturn(...) - your method actually invoked and just return object replaced by mock. There are cases, when you don't want your method is executed at all, so you may use another stubbing approach - doReturn(...).when(...).

Comment: Share a bit more details about exception you got.

Comment: I moved when( ). thenReturn( ) to doReturn( ).when() because the anotherMethod() throws the exception. After moving, there is no exception, but I am getting responseObj as null which inturn throws NullPointerException since I am accessing it for sending a part of it as a response of methodToTest()

Answer (score -1):

Although [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378486/4427870) by @arsen_adzhiametov is correct and up to the mark I would like to contribute how I do it.

In this case, I am mocking the value of `HomeClient` which internally is a WebClient that calls out another service for some values.

`TestClass.java` (Please name it better)

```
...
import org.mockito.Mockito;
...

class TestClass {
    HomeClient mockHomeClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        mockHomeClient = Mockito.mock(HomeClient.class);
        
        // Axon specific test code. Can ignore if not using Axon.
        fixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(SomeAgreegate.class);
        fixture.registerInjectableResource(mockHomeClient);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testOpenOperation() throws HomeClientException {
        Mockito.when(mockHomeClient.getXYZ("nice")).thenReturn(2);
        // Do what you will with your code and call the method which you want to test
        // Mockito will mock the `HomeClient` in this case and `getXYZ` will return `2`
        // You can also change the mock response any time in the same function
        Mockito.when(mockHomeClient.getXYZ("nice")).thenReturn(-100);

        // Or specify different results on mock when different values are provided
        Mockito.when(mockHomeClient.getXYZ("nice")).thenReturn(1);
        Mockito.when(mockHomeClient.getXYZ("foo")).thenReturn(100);        
        Mockito.when(mockHomeClient.getXYZ("bar")).thenReturn(0);


    }
}
```